# Predict R function is not returning confidence interval, why?

Tags: r, time-series, prediction

I have a Garch model for which I want to get a confidence interval.

I have tried the following using the function predict, as I've been told to use that specific R function, but so far I only get two columns full of prediction data, there's no confidence interval which I understant it's supposed to be.

My code is as follows (here dades is where the data is contained):

```
mod2<-garch(dades, order=c(0,1), include.mean=F)
predict(mod2,interval="confidence")
```

Predict then behave as I've explained, it returns:

```
[1,]        NA         NA
[2,] 0.2169800 -0.2169800
[3,] 0.2906891 -0.2906891
[4,] 0.2623098 -0.2623098
[5,] 0.1813793 -0.1813793
[6,] 0.1681774 -0.1681774
[7,] 0.4067880 -0.4067880
[8,] ...
```

And for what I understand, it should return something like

```
     fit      lwr      upr
1    n1       n2       n3
```

EDIT: My dades is in this file https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-CzRGmTYN0ExR_y3r-bWPLwPQFqFK3RP

I have read is as follows (I have dst.txt in local folder):

```
dades<-read.table("dst.txt", hearder=T)
```

Comment: Please share your data `dades` so people can help you find a solution

Comment: Why would you expect to get that? `?predict.garch` - "*Value: For ‘predict’ a bivariate time series (two-column matrix) of predictions.*"